# Oauth2 PKCE - What security does "S256" provide over "plain"?

Tags: hash, man-in-the-middle, oauth2

The Oauth PKCE protocol flow is as follows, as defined in [RFC 7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636#section-1.1):

```
                                             +-------------------+
                                             |   Authz Server    |
   +--------+                                | +---------------+ |
   |        |--(A)- Authorization Request ---->|               | |
   |        |       + t(code_verifier), t_m  | | Authorization | |
   |        |                                | |    Endpoint   | |
   |        |<-(B)---- Authorization Code -----|               | |
   |        |                                | +---------------+ |
   | Client |                                |                   |
   |        |                                | +---------------+ |
   |        |--(C)-- Access Token Request ---->|               | |
   |        |          + code_verifier       | |    Token      | |
   |        |                                | |   Endpoint    | |
   |        |<-(D)------ Access Token ---------|               | |
   +--------+                                | +---------------+ |
                                             +-------------------+
```

My question is: why do we need to use a trapdoor like `S256` in step (A)?

According to the RFC's threat model, a malicious app cannot intercept the *outgoing* communication in (A) or (C). So why can't an app generate and temporarily store a random value in (A) and re-use it in (C)?

To elaborate: the goal of `t(code_verifier)` (ie `S256(code_verifier)`) is to later enable the app to prove to the server that it is indeed the app as it possess `code_verifier` before the transform.

However, if the app just sent `code_verifier` and later sent it again, the same guarantee is achieved: the server receives a random value that uniquely identifies the app, and receives it again. No other app can provide this value: as long as the connection isn't intercepted (and it shouldn't be - TLS), `S256` seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I can't read, apparently. The justification is described in the RFC itself:

```
A number of pre-conditions need to hold for this attack to work:

[...]

  4. Either one of the following condition is met:

      4a. The attacker (via the installed application) is able to
          observe only the responses from the authorization endpoint.
          When "code_challenge_method" value is "plain", only this
          attack is mitigated.

      4b. A more sophisticated attack scenario allows the attacker to
          observe requests (in addition to responses) to the
          authorization endpoint.  The attacker is, however, not able to
          act as a man in the middle.  This was caused by leaking http
          log information in the OS.  To mitigate this,
          "code_challenge_method" value must be set either to "S256" or
          a value defined by a cryptographically secure
          "code_challenge_method" extension.
```

`plain` is enough for the threat model described in my question, but `S256` is indeed necessary for a more advanced threat model.

Now I am wondering: if the attacker can observe all responses, what is stopping the attacker from observing the final access token response?

Why does this threat model restrict request/response observation vulnerabilities only to the authorization endpoint?

Comment: I think because if an attacker can observe responses from the token endpoint too he can probably observe all responses, and so probably has root access, which can't be mitigated against.

Comment: Interesting. Under what circumstances would an attacker be able to intercept the first response, but not the second? (This is why the threat model seems a bit arbitrary to me - I'm sure I'm missing something)

Comment: Off the top of my head I would suggest that the two endpoints may mean one route could be compromised and the other not.  If you were to compromise the client though you could skip A, B, and C and focus on D.  So it may be more theoretical than practical, but I may be missing something too.

Comment: @tusing The response from the authorization endpoint is really quite different from the final access token response. The authorization endpoint responds with a redirect to the redirect_uri containing the authorization code as parameter. This means that this response might shop up in places like http logs and browser history, which makes leaking the authorization code a lot more plausible. The final access token response instead is just a plain http response body.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, we can assume that the code exchange (C + D) happens in the back channel (back end to back end) and is safe from any client-side attack. Intercepting the code in **a redirect** from the auth server to the client is fundamentally easier than intercepting something from between your own client's front end and back end.

One way to get the intuition is this. If the request has already made its way to your client back end, un-hijacked, you have strong control over what you serve to the client front end. If you give the access token to the front end via another redirect then, yeah, you might be in trouble since someone could potentially hijack that. But even then, the attacker will have had to be contextually aware of when to hijack and when to not.